# Chebyshev's, Gauss' and Vysochanski˘i-Petunin Inequalities for uniform and normal distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, chebyshev-polynomials

so I am being asked to compare the bounds obtained by these three inequalities mentioned in the title for a r.v. following a uniform distribution [0,1] and a r.v. following N(u,1)

I am struggling hugely as to how go about this so any help would be appreciated! 
I know the formula's for Chebyshev's but not sure how I go about getting the actual bounds!

Comment: Could you write out the inequalities in your post?

Comment: I could provide a picture one sec!

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/a2m4j5bxp/